# Does CUDA signbit() remove divergence?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have seen that some people suggest that using [signbit()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE_1g65d4410ff1132a74d16ada02d2be686f) can eliminate warp divergence and improve performance. If this is correct, then how is it implemented in the GPU? Is there some dedicated hardware for this function in, e.g., special function units (SFU)?

Comment: I would be very surprised if it is implemented in hardware. Checking the sign only requires returning the state of the IEEE 754 sign bit, and that is trivially done with a bit mask

Comment: Thanks. By hardware my question was that if it is just a simple macro that is replaced by if-condition! But I guess that is not the case.

Comment: If you look at the header file `math_functions.h` in CUDA versions <= 6.5, you can see that `signbit()` is implemented as a macro that maps to an inline function that simply extracts the sign bit from the underlying bit pattern (with a right shift in the version I looked at). This is cheap on the GPU, since integer and floating-point operands share the same registers. So `signbit()` is non-branchy and efficient; there is no dedicated hardware instruction. CUDA users should not be overly concerned about branches, the compiler can often remove them through predication or select-type instructions

Comment: @njuffa if you want to provide an answer, I would up-vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of `signbit()` is in the open in CUDA versions up to, and including, CUDA 6.5. It can be found in the header file `math_functions.h`. For newer versions of CUDA, you could inspect the machine code with `cubobjdump --dump-sass` to see how it is implemented.

Looking at the header file in CUDA 6.5, one sees that `signbit()` is a macro that maps to an inline function that extracts the sign bit from the raw bit representation for the floating-point operand. On GPUs this is easily doable since integer and floating-point operands share the same register file. In case of CUDA 6.5, the sign bit is extracted with a single right-shift instruction.

So the implementation of `signbit()` is branchless and efficient, however there is no dedicated hardware instruction for it, as this is unnecessary.

In general, CUDA programmer's do not need to worry about branches all that often, especialy when `if-then-else` constructs with small bodies are concerned. The compiler frequently renders these into branchless code using either predication of select-type instructions (the machine equivalent of C/C++ ternary operator). It may also combine uniform branches with predication.